# Mongoose - Populate only array items that meet a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

consider the following models:

```js
const Band = new Schema({
    name: String,
    genre: String,
    venues: [{
        city: String,
        venue: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Venue'}
    }]
});

const Venue = new Schema({
    arena: String,
    // Some more venue details...
});
```

Now, for example, I want to find all bands with `genre == 'country'` that perform in `city == 'nashville'`,
and only populate the corresponding venues array entry.
Meaning only the array entry with `city == 'nashville'` (we can assume there's only 1 of it) will have the venue details and all the other entries will only have an ObjectId.

Edit: Added Example (as requested on comments):

```js
const bands = [
    {
        name: 'band-a',
        genre: 'country',
        venues: [
            { city: 'nashville', venue: 'objectId(a)' },
            { city: 'portland', venue: 'objectId(b)' },
        ]
    }
];

const venues = [
    { _id: 'a', arena: 'some-arena' },
    { _id: 'b', arena: 'some-other-arena' }
]

const result = [{
    name: 'band-a',
    genre: 'country',
    venues: [
        { city: 'nashville', venue: { _id: 'a', arena: 'some-arena' } },
        { city: 'portland', venue: 'objectId(b)' },
    ]  
}]
```

Is there a way to achieve this kind of conditional population?

Comment: Can you please give sample documents for band and venue collection in json format and the expected output?

Comment: @SuleymanSah added example. Hope it's clear.

Comment: Why do you keep city both in bands.venues and venue?

Comment: Ideally since you have city as part of venue (should be), `city` from band model could be removed isn't it?

Comment: City is in venue just for reference. It can be removed. I'll remove it from the question now just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Also why do you wan't to populate venue only for  `city == 'nashville'` ? Is it really necessary?

Comment: @SuleymanSah mostly data transfer costs and limitations.

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done with mongoose populate, but you can try to implement this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53711339/11717458) with aggregation framework.